# Trouble uploading html zipfile to Google Adworks

Tags: html, google-ads-api, adobe-animate

[image]

Hey

I’m having trouble uploading a html5 banner advert to Google Adworks, it passes all of the checks apart from the relative asset check.

I get this error message come up and I’m not sure what the solution is. I’ve tried removing the bit of code
 but this doesn’t work and ends up making the artwork blank when I preview it in the browser.